# Nodejs crashes under stress testing

Tags: node.js, testing

I am trying to simulate 1000 websocket connections to a test server.I thought implementing it using cluster.fork, but using it 1000 time will deplete my memory and crash the computer.Async seems to be a solution to the problem,however i still ran out of memory.How am i supposed to conduct such a test while being at the same time careful with my resources?If i use numCpus instead of 500 , i only get 4 connections.

edit :

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    //This is the master control process
    console.log("Control process running: PID=" + process.pid);
    //Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        worker = cluster.fork();

        //Receive messages from this worker and handle them in the master process.
        worker.on('message', function(msg) {
            console.log('Master ' + process.pid + ' received message from worker ' + msg);
        });
    }
if (cluster.isWorker) {
    console.log('Worker ' + process.pid + ' has started.');

    websocketCreation();//function that creates new WebSockets
    eventHandler();//function that handles on error,close and messagr
}
```

Comment: Post your code.  At the moment it's unclear what you're saying your code does... do you `cluster.fork()` 1000 times, once for each connection?  If so, that's the wrong strategy.  If you post your code, then we can actually attempt to help you.

Comment: You might've inadvertently created a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) which is fairly common if you get your logic wrong. What you're doing here looks like the way to do it, so why that's happening isn't clear.